# All the ternary n-words with an even sum of digits and a zero.

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find a recursive formula for all the ternary (using ${0,1,2}$) sequences of length $n$ which contain at least one zero, and have an even sum of digits.

My attempt so far is added below. I think the idea is right, but the recurrence relation I get fails when setting in numbers (and it's not always an integer..). any ideas?

> Denote with $f\left(n\right)$ the number of legal sequences as in the question, $\bar{f}\left(n\right)$ as the number of sequences with at least one 0 with an odd number of digits, and as $g\left(n\right)$ the number of sequences with an even sum of digits and with no zeroes.
>
> For any sequence, the sum of digits would be even if and only if there is an even number of 1s, therefore any legal sequence of length $n$ can be achieved in a unique way out of the following:
>
> • Starting from a sequence where the digits are even and there is no zero, append zero at the end. There are $g\left(n-1\right)$ such sequences.
>
> • Starting from a legal sequence of length $n-1$, append 0 or 2 at the end, adding $2f\left(n-1\right)$ sequences.
>
> • Starting from a sequence with a zero where the sum of digits is odd, append 1 at the end, adding $\bar{f}\left(n-1\right)$ sequences.
>
> These gives us that $$f\left(n\right)=2f\left(n-1\right)+\bar{f}\left(n-1\right)+g\left(n-1\right)$$
>
> Considering $g\left(n\right)$ first, we are interested in strings of length n from $\left\{ 1,2\right\} $ with an even number of 1s. There's a simple bijection to the set of strings of length $n$ with an odd number of 1s by “flipping” the first value, and as these sets include all possibilities with no overlap, it follows that $g\left(n\right)=2^{n-1}$.
>
> Next looking at $\bar{f}\left(n-1\right)$. We can use the fact that the sequences with a zero where the sum of digits is odd and the sequences with a zero where the sum of digits is even are exactly a disjoint union of all the sequences with a zero.
>
> As there are $n\cdot3^{n-1}$ such sequences (we first choose one location to be 0, and fill the rest normally), we get that $\bar{f}\left(n\right)+f\left(n\right)=n\cdot3^{n-1}$, or $\bar{f}\left(n\right)=n\cdot3^{n-1}-f\left(n\right)$
>
> Putting this all together we get that $$f\left(n\right)=2f\left(n-1\right)+\left(n-1\right)\cdot3^{n-2}-f\left(n-1\right)+2^{n-2}
>  or f\left(n\right)=f\left(n-1\right)+\left(n-1\right)\cdot3^{n-2}+2^{n-2}$$

Comment: In the definition of $\overline f(n)$, it should be an odd sum of digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $E(n)$ count the number of ternary $n$-strings with even sum, and let $e(n)$ count the number of *binary* $n$-strings, using just the digits $1$ and $2$, with even sum.  You want a formula for

$$f(n)=E(n)-e(n)$$

We first note that $e(n)=2^{n-1}$, since the parity of the last digit is determined by the choice of the first $n-1$ digits.  As for $E(n)$, if we let $O(n)$ count the number of ternary $n$-strings with odd sum, we see that

$$E(n)=2E(n-1)+O(n-1)=2E(n-1)+(3^{n-1}-E(n-1))=E(n-1)+3^{n-1}$$

Putting these together, we have

$$\begin{align}
f(n)&=E(n)-2^{n-1}\\
&=E(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\\
&=E(n-1)-2^{n-2}+2^{n-2}+3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\\
&=f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}
\end{align}$$

As a sanity check, we know that $f(1)=1$, so we get

$$\begin{align}
f(2)&=1+3-1=3\\
f(3)&=3+9-2=10
\end{align}$$

which can be easily checked by hand. (I find it extremely helpful to run sanity checks, because I almost always make at least one mistake when first deriving a formula.  This case was no exception.)

Remark:  Once you have the recursive formula $f(n)=f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}$, it's not hard to prove (by induction) the formula $f(n)=(3^n-2^n+1)/2$ (see [Jack D'Aurizio's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584524/all-the-ternary-n-words-with-an-even-sum-of-digits-and-a-zero/1584561#1584561)):

$$\begin{align}
f(n)&={3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}+1\over2}+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}\\
&={3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}+1+2\cdot3^{n-1}-2^{n-1}\over2}\\
&={(1+2)3^{n-1}-2\cdot2^{n-1}+1\over2}\\
&={3^n-2^n+1\over2}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 4):

The recurrence approach is not strictly needed. The parity of the digit sum obviously depends on the number of $1$s only; the number of ternary strings having length $n$ with exactly $k$ digits $1$ and at least one digit $0$ is $\binom{n}{k}\cdot\left(2^{n-k}-1\right)$. The answer is so:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2j}\left(2^{n-2j}-1\right)&=&-2^{n-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor}\binom{n}{2j}2^{n-2j}\\&=&-2^{n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}((-1)^k+1^k)\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{3^n-2^n+1}{2}}.\end{eqnarray*} $$
That makes sense: we have $2^n$ strings without digits $0$, and among the remaining $3^n-2^n$ it is reasonable to expect that about half of them has an even digit sum.

Answer (score 4):

Inspired by Jack D'Aurizio's post:

There are $\ 3^n$ ternary strings of length $\ n$ altogether, and $\ 2^n$ have no $\ 0$. Of the remaining $\ 3^n - 2^n$, one is the string with nothing but $\ 0$, and the rest have at least one non-zero element. As you noted in your own proof, the map that swaps the first non-zero element between $\ 1$ and $\ 2$ is a bijection between those strings with even and odd sums. So $$\frac{3^n - 2^n - 1}{2}$$ of them will be even. Adding in the $\ 0$-string as also having an even sum gives $$\frac{3^n - 2^n + 1}{2}$$
as the number of strings with at least one $\ 0$ and even sum.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is the count of $\overline f(n-1)$.  In the next paragraph, you are counting $\overline f(n)$, not $\overline f(n-1)$.  You also count strings with more than one zero multiple times.  The string $0001$ would be counted three times, once for each zero.  I don't see how you get non-integral values--there is no division anywhere.

Added:  I would also define $\overline g(n)$ as the strings of odd sum and no zeros.  Your argument that $g(n)=2^{n-1}$ applies to $\overline g(n)$ as well.  Your recurrence for $f(n)$ is fine.  To get $\overline f(n)$ you can start with $\overline f(n-1)$ and append a $0$ or $2$,start with a string of length $n-1$ and even sum and append a $1$, or start with a string of length $n-1$ with odd sum and no zeros and append a zero.  Your argument for $g(n)$ applies to the last, so $\overline f(n)=2\overline f(n-1)+f(n-1)++\overline g(n-1)=2\overline f(n-1)+f(n-1)$+2^{n-2}$

Comment: got it specifically for n=1 with starting condition f(0)=1 because of the 2. And yeah.. f-bar is wrong. always confused by these...

Comment: About your addition: This is exactly what I did originally, but what about even strings of lenght n-1 with zeroes? you can add 1 to then, so I also need $f(n) $ in the definition of f-bar, which puts me in a loop

Comment: Yes, you get coupled recurrences.  You can substitute the expression for $\overline f(n-1)$ into the one for $f(n)$, which will give you a second order recurrence for $f(n)$.  You can also make a vector out of $f(n), \overline f(n)$ and a $2 \times 2$ matrix that multiplies the vector for the recurrence.  You then look for eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the matrix.  They amount to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to Barry's answer above, here I show how to solve for the closed form of the recurrence relation directly.

Given the recurrence of the form $f(n)=f(n-1)+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}$ and the initial condition $f(1)=1$ we first find what the homogeneous solution will look like.

The characteristic polynomial will be of the form $x-1=0$, so we know the final solution will be of the form: $f(n)=c_1\cdot (1)^n + p(n)$ for some particular solution $p(n)$.

Given our non-homogenous part, we expect $p(n)=d_13^n+d_22^n$ for some constants $d_1$ and $d_2$.  Plugging this in for $f(n)$ and $f(n-1)$ respectively we have:

$d_13^n+d_22^n=d_13^{n-1}+d_22^{n-1}+3^{n-1}-2^{n-2}$

By grouping similarly ordered terms, this implies the following system of equations:

$\begin{cases}3d_1=d_1+1\\4d_2=2d_2-1\end{cases}$

which implies $d_1=\frac{1}{2}$ and $d_2=-\frac{1}{2}$

So, we have $f(n)=c_1+\frac{1}{2}3^n-\frac{1}{2}2^n$

Using our initial condition, we solve for $c_1$

$1=c_1+\frac{1}{2}3^1-\frac{1}{2}2^1=c_1+\frac{1}{2}$ implying $c_1=\frac{1}{2}$

Thus, $f(n)=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}3^n-\frac{1}{2}2^n=\frac{3^n-2^n+1}{2}$